# How to jump to a specific div which placed bottom of page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, web-applications, web

I have a div which located at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I want to go to this div after performing of my JS-function. In other words, I want to have my url become `myurl#myDiv` and to go to my div. But without reloading the page. How this can be done using JavaScript? Unfortunately I have not found a working solution for this issue. I am not using any JS-libraries and frameworks.

Comment: David's answer is the better solution, with it *any DOM element (with or without an ID) can be scrolled into view.* With my answer you can only scroll to an ID/anchor on the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the window's location to that of the ID. The browser will then scroll to that element.

```
window.location.hash = '#myDiv';
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. However, it did work with `location.href` in a brief test—though IE would probably choke.

Comment: This worked for me in the latest Firefox, but didn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 36):

To scroll to a particular element, use, [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView), supported by IE6+ and real browsers:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollIntoView();
```

Check `window.location.hash` on DOMReady, to see if there is a hash in the URL matching any element in your document.

If there are `#myDiv` links within the document, you would need to add `onclick` listeners to them, perform the scroll manually, as per the code above, and `return false` to avoid following the link to `#myDiv`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3n4n/)

Comment: +1 `IE6+ and real browsers`: you're right, IE 6 is not a real browser in _this day and age_ anymore ;)

Answer (score 4):

The **scrollIntoView(true)** method also accepts a parameter specifies whether to align to top (true) or bottom (false).